# Security Scan causing weird logs

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, php, debian, security

So some time ago, I coded a website(PHP) and wanted to check for common web security vulnerability. I used Nessus and Burp Suite to scan for vulnerabilities in my website. The scan result showed no major threats, and cause a lot of data in my logs, then I decided to go through the logs and I discovered some weird entries, it seems like the server tried to access itself "without a session" and that sounds like a potential vulnerability, does anyone has any idea?

[First occurance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKXl3.png)

[Second Occurance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mkvz3.png)

I wasn't sure where to post this so I posted here if it's the wrong forum feel free to tell me.
Note: This is a Debian server with up to date packages. If you need any code just ask and I'll edit the question

Comment: Who writes this log entries - your PHP application?

Comment: Yes my PHP application writes the logs

Comment: Those are custom log entries, presumably from your own code. Why does your code log them?

Comment: @MichaelHampton when someone accesses a script/page in a way they shouldn't example they're not logged in or with an invalid sessions ID or something like that my code logs that because it's suspicious but as you can see the wrong access is from 127.0.0.1 not a regular IP address